# Salt stack: how to set up a package installation check with Chocolate (state)

Tags: salt-stack, chocolatey

During the execution of the state, the manager "Chocolate" installs the package RealVNC (Program Files\Real VNC)
Next, I create a key in the registry.
I want the keys to be created only if the VNC installation was successful.
I have tried

```
Require:
  - pkg: realvnc

Watch:
  - file: C:\Program Files\Real VNC\vncserver.exe
```

Both options tell me that the target is not found

Sls

```
      realvncsetup:
        chocolatey.installed:
          - name: realvnc

      reg1:
        reg.present:
          - name: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\RealVNC\vncserver
          - vname: EnableAnalytics
          - vdata: "0"
          - vtype: REG_SZ
          - watch:
            - file: "C:\\Program Files\\RealVNC\\VNC Server"
```

Error

```
ID: reg1
    Function: reg.present
        Name: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\RealVNC\vncserver
      Result: False
     Comment: The following requisites were not found:
                                 require:
                                     file: C:\Program Files\RealVNC\VNC Server
     Started: 12:39:20.183205
    Duration: 0.0 ms
     Changes:
```

salt --versions

```
Salt Version:
           Salt: 3002.1
 
Dependency Versions:
           cffi: 1.12.2
       cherrypy: unknown
       dateutil: 2.7.3
      docker-py: 3.4.1
          gitdb: 2.0.5
      gitpython: 2.1.11
         Jinja2: 2.10
        libgit2: 0.27.7
       M2Crypto: Not Installed
           Mako: 1.0.7
   msgpack-pure: Not Installed
 msgpack-python: 0.5.6
   mysql-python: 1.3.10
      pycparser: 2.19
       pycrypto: 2.6.1
   pycryptodome: 3.6.1
         pygit2: 0.27.4
         Python: 3.7.3 (default, Jul 25 2020, 13:03:44)
   python-gnupg: 0.4.4
         PyYAML: 3.13
          PyZMQ: 17.1.2
          smmap: 2.0.5
        timelib: Not Installed
        Tornado: 4.5.3
            ZMQ: 4.3.1
 
System Versions:
           dist: debian 10 buster
         locale: UTF-8
        machine: x86_64
        release: 4.19.0-6-amd64
         system: Linux
        version: Debian GNU/Linux 10 buster
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requisites that we mention, such as `require`, `watch`, etc. should be references to other states that are "scheduled" to run on the targets.

**About `watch`**

Even though the path is created by installing the "realvnc" package, there is no Salt state to handle the path. That is why it is showing the error.

Quoting from [documentation](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html#requisites-watch) for `watch`:

> A `watch` requisite is used to add additional behavior when there are changes in other states.

So if you want to watch on a file, then there should be a state that "handles" the file using the `file` module.

**About `require`**

Also, while specifying `require` you are referring to `pkg` module, so Saltstack would look for `pkg.installed` for realvnc. Whereas you are using `chocolatey.installed`.

So with below modifications it should work fine.

```yaml
chocolatey-install-realvnc:
  chocolatey.installed:
  - name: realvnc

# Use the appropriate path that should exist when realvnc is installed
check-progfiles-path:
  file.exists:
  - name: 'C:\Program Files\Real VNC\vncserver.exe'

# You can use either or both for require as you see fit
create-registry-entry:
  reg.present:
  - name: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\RealVNC\vncserver
  - vname: EnableAnalytics
  - vdata: "0"
  - vtype: REG_SZ
  - require:
    - file: 'C:\Program Files\Real VNC\vncserver.exe'
    - chocolatey: realvnc
```